# Get all values from a multidimensional array as a flat , indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have this array:

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "14"
    }
    [1]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [1]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "11"
}
```

is there some PHP function with output all values in one string. Like this:

```
    array(5){
    [0]=>
    string(2) "14"

    [1]=>
    string(2) "12"

    [2]=>
    string(2) "13"

     [3]=>
    string(2) "11"
}
```

Comment: Please no more :O Loop through entire array and fetch string type data in new 1D array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$output = array();
array_walk_recursive($inputArray,
   create_function('$val, $key, $obj', 'array_push($obj, $val);'), &output)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with php 5.3.3. Are you sure you can pass $output by value instead of by reference?

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = array();
array_walk_recursive($ar, function($v, $k, $res) {
  $res[] = $v;
}, &$res);
```

Comment: this only works in php 5.3, right? (confused about the use of `function`)

Comment: Before 5.3, you'd write `create_function('$v, $k, $res', '$res[] = $v;');`

Comment: . the new notation is better. (still stuck at 5.2 here)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of some of the [SPL](http://php.net/spl)'s iterators<sup>[1](http://php.net/recursivearrayiterator),[2](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator)</sup>   and the `iterator_to_array()`<sup>[3](http://php.net/iterator_to_array)</sup> function, to save yourself the work of anonymous callbacks.

```
$leaves = iterator_to_array(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
    ),
    FALSE
);
```

**Refs**

1. `RecursiveArrayIterator` http://php.net/recursivearrayiterator
2. `RecursiveIteratorIterator` http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator
3. `iterator_to_array()` http://php.net/iterator_to_array

Answer (score 0):

```
function flatten_array(array $a) 
{
   array_walk_recursive($a, function($v) use(&$r) { $r[] = $v; });
   return $r;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't. You will have to write your own.

Answer (score -1):

You won't get exactly what you want, but you could see [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).