# PHP foreach() with arrays within arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I want to call a function on each element in an array. This is obviously very easy with a `foreach()`, but where I start breaking down is when arrays contain arrays. Can someone help me out with a function that will execute some code for every key -> value pair from a set of arrays within arrays. The depth could, in theory, be infinite, but a good limit would be 3 iterations (array in array in array) if recursion couldn't work.

An example array would be one taken from $_POST below:

```
Array
(
    [languages] => Array
    (
        [0] => php
        [1] => mysql
        [2] => inglip
    )

    [rates] => Array
    (
        [incall] => Array
        (
            [1hr] => 10
        )

        [outcall] => Array
        (
            [1hr] => 10
        )

    )
)
```

Just to make sure, what I want to do is run a piece of code (a function) that is passed every 'end node' in the array structure, so in the example above, it would be called when...

```
[0] => php
[1] => mysql
[2] => inglip
[1hr] => 10
[1hr] => 10
```

... is found.

Thanks for any help,

James

Comment: *(sidenote)* The correct term for "end node" is leaf.

Comment: also see [Get All Values in One Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450249/get-all-values-in-one-array-php). It's not strictly a duplicate, but highly related.

Comment: Also have a look at `bool array_walk_recursive( ... )` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's a perfect job for [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

See [Introduction to SPL Iterators](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html) and [Live Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/A68lcnLZ)

**EDIT:** the alternative would be [`array_walk_recursive` as show in Finbarr's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524227/php-foreach-with-arrays-within-arrays/5524307#5524307)

Answer (score 11):

See [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) - a PHP library function that recursively calls a user defined function against a provided array.

From PHP docs:

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Output:

```
a holds apple
b holds banana
sour holds lemon
```

Note that `Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.`.

EDIT: slightly less ugly example:

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');
array_walk_recursive($fruits, function ($item, $key) {
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
});
?>
```

Comment: +1 Next to my own answer this is the only practical approach to the problem. All those userland recursive functions are just ridiculous. You might want to add a small usage example though to illustrate usage.

Comment: @Jam `array_walk_recursive` perfectly fits "call a function on each element in an array" though. but okay, I wont complain about an accepted answer :) Will edit mine to include a link here though. Thanks!

Comment: No complaints from this end. They were both perfectly valid answers. There are many ways to solve the same problem, and it is down to the programmer to choose whatever way suits them.

Comment: The _only_ slight niggle I have with this answer is having to reference the function name as a string. To me, it's cleaner to use the RecursiveIterator function.

Comment: Well, as with all PHP library functions that are designed to callback you could pass an anonymous function directly to `array_walk_recursive` - you need not use the function name as string.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, in this kind of situation, you'll have to write a [**recursive function**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) -- which will deal with an item if it's not an array ; and call itself on an item if it's an array.

Here, you could have something like this :

```
$arr = array(
    'languages' => array(
        'php', 'mysql', 'inglip', 
    ), 
    'rates' => array(
        'incall' => array('1hr' => 10), 
        'outcall' => array('1hr' => 10), 
    ), 
);

function recurse($item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recurse($value);
        } else {
            echo "$key : $value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And calling this recursive function on your array :

```
recurse($arr);
```

Would get you :

```
0 : php
1 : mysql
2 : inglip
1hr : 10
1hr : 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple reusable implementation:

```
function recursive_foreach($array, $callback) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recursive_foreach($value, $callback);
        }
        else {
            call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `$callback` is a callback accepting two arguments: key and value. For example:

```
recursive_foreach($array, function($k, $v) {
    echo "$k => $v<br>";
});
```

Comment: Did not know that PHP supported anonymous functions!

Comment: @Finbarr @Jon PHP supported anonymous functions before 5.3, too with the `create_function` function. It's just awkward to use and slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getEndNodes($input, $ret = array()) {

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($input[$key])) {
            $ret[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $ret = getEndNodes($input[$key],$ret);
        }
    }

    return $ret;

}


// Usage: 
$endNodes = getEndNodes($yourarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call a function on each element in an array. This is obviously very easy with a foreach()

If you want to run a function on every element of a deep array, you can use [array_walk_recursive()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k)
{  
    echo "$k => $v\n";
});
```

If you want to iterate over each element with `foreach`, you need a recursive iterator as mentionned previously.

If you're not sure which one to use, go with `foreach` + recursive iterator. It's easier to grasp for most people.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_spelunk($array = array()) {
    foreach($array as $key => $node) {
        if (is_array($node)) {
            array_spelunk($node);
        } else {
           echo "[$key] [$node]\n";
        }
    }
}

array_spelunk($your_nested_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function recurse($element, $key = null) {
  if(is_array($element)) {
    foreach($element as $k => $v) {
      recurse($v, $k);
    }
  }else{
    //Do what you want here. $element is value, $key is the key
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function traverseArray($array)
{ 
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    { 
        if(is_array($value))
        { 
            traverseArray($value); 
        }else{
            echo '['.$key.']'.' => '.$value.'<br />\n'; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the first thing I came up with. Thanks for the effort in posting your answer, but it's not an ideal solution to say the least.