# PHP arrays within arrays in session

Tags: php, arrays

I've been using PHP for a little bit, but only doing basic tasks, and have gotten stuck while trying to build part of a knowledgebase.

While creating an article, you can upload screenshots - these need to be stored in a staging area until the article is saved, and I've got their information saved into the users session.

In POST upload:

```
...
$new_ss = array();
$new_ss['display_name'] = $ss_name;
$new_ss['server_path'] = "../uploads/";    /* outside of doc root */
$new_ss['server_path'] .= hash_file('md5', $ss_tmp_name) . "_" . $ss_name;

if ( @move_uploaded_file($ss_tmp_name, $new_ss['server_path']) )
{
    $_SESSION['article']['screenshots'] .= $new_ss;
    ...
```

Then trying to display the upload to the user within the editing page:

```
if ( is_array($_SESSION['article']['screenshots']) && count($_SESSION['article']['screenshots']) > 0 )
{
    echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
    foreach ( $_SESSION['article']['screenshots'] as $ss )
    {
        ... display table of uploaded images ...
```

The trouble is, PHP isn't seeing $_SESSION['article']['screenshots'] as an array - and I can't see why.

After following the answer here:
[PHP foreach() with arrays within arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524227/php-foreach-with-arrays-within-arrays) I tried quickly doing the following:

```
function print_array($key, $item) {
    echo "$key -> $item\n";
}

...
{
    $_SESSION['article']['screenshots'] .= $new_ss;
    array_walk_recurisve($_SESSION['article']['screenshots'], 'print_array');
    ...
```

however I get the error "expects parameter 1 to be array, string given".

If I do an 'error_log($_SESSION['article']['screenshots']);' it just prints "Array" for however many images are uploaded, and print_r just printed '1' by itself.

Can someone shed some light please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not really sure which of your key should be an array, in this line:

```
$_SESSION['article']['screenshots'] .= $new_ss;
```

You're making it a string by concatenating it. If you want to append as an array, you should probably do this:

```
 $_SESSION['article']['screenshots'][] = $new_ss;
```

Comment: Argh, so simple! Was stuck in the mindset of 'appending to', and that operator was it... working now thanks! Will accept once I'm allowed to!