# Multidimensional Array for() with different numbered elements levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I write a foreach loop that would print off all information with the following multidimensional array without using any functions:

```
$workers = array(
    "Natalie" => array
        ("First term" => array(
              "Subworker" => "Susan", 
               "Length" => '1900-2000', 
                "Notes" => "Finished all tasks"),                     
      "Second term" => array(
               "Subworker" => "Laura", 
             "Length" => '1985-1986'), 
           ),               
      "Laura" => array(
            "First term" => array(
                  "Subworker" => "Sarah", 
                  "Length" => '1999-1992'),                     
             ),               
        "Carolyn" => array(
             "First term" => array(
                  "Subworker" => "Jenny", 
                  "Length" => '1900 -1945', 
                  "Notes" => array
                         ("Finished all tasks", 
                           "Did not finish all tasks",                           
                           "Completed partial tasks" )
                  ),                    
                  ),               
        "Jacob" => array(
            "First term" => array(
                "Subworker" => "Danielle", 
                "Length" => '1993-1994', 
                "Notes" => "Finished all tasks"),                       
                ),   
        "Jenny" => array(
           "First term" => array(
                "Subworker" => "Angela", 
                "Length" => '1999 - 2001'),                      
           "Second term" =>        array(
              "Subworker" => array(
                    "Paula" => "Let Go", 
                    "Steve" => "Hired"), 
              "Length" => '1987 - 1999', 
              "Notes" => "Hired"),                              
            )              
        );
```

/****So far I've done the following, but it is not printing out everything. For example, it is not printing out under Jenny, Second term, Subworker Paula and Steve./*****

```
foreach($workers as $worker => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $newkey => $info) {
         echo $worker.':<br>'.$newkey.':<br>';
             foreach ($value as $newkey) {
                 echo 'Subworker: '.$newkey["Subkey"].'<BR>';
                     foreach ($value as $newkey) {
                         echo 'Length: '.$newkey["Length"].'<BR>';
                            foreach ($value as $newkey) {
                            echo 'Notes: '.$newkey["Notes"].'<BR>';             
               }
           }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach() with arrays within arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524227/php-foreach-with-arrays-within-arrays)

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate, since this has the constraint that no functions should be used. Although I wonder: what is the problem with functions?

Comment: This here is working on your array: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e6acc9c674b82d25468e086fc74477851d5669b Added an `array_key_exists`, a `is_array`, and another `foreach` loop. I can write up an answer but want to clean up the code first.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, as far as I can see, that code will fail when the array is nested deeper than in the sample.

Comment: @trincot Yes. That's how I interpret the question. "...print off all information with the following multidimensional array without using any functions"

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to cross by a function and to make small tests upstream, it is always useful to avoid the return of error in environment of dev. :)

I have to add lists (ul, li) for better one reading

```
if (is_array($workers) && !empty($workers)) {
    echo loopArray($workers);
} else {
    echo "<ul><li>".$workers."</li></ul>";
}

function loopArray($array)
{
    $result = "";
    $result .= "<ul>";
    foreach ($array as $item => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $result .= "<li>".$item;
            $result .= loopArray($value)."</li>";
        } else {
            $result .= "<ul><li>".$item.': '.$value."</li></ul>";
        }
    }
    $result .= "</ul>";

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I can print out all relevant information without using functions and only foreach loops

Comment: change : [...] foreach ($value as $newkey) [...] by [...] foreach ($value as $newKey as $newValue) [...]

Answer (score 0):

To print *the particular* array you've provided, without using functions:

```
// workers
foreach($workers as $worker => $workerarr) {
  echo $worker.":<ul>\n";

  // worker terms
  foreach ($workerarr as $term => $terminfo) {
    echo "<li>$term:<ul>\n";

    // term info
    foreach ($terminfo as $type => $typevalue) {
      echo "<li>$type: ";

      // is type value an array?
      if ( is_array($typevalue) ) {

        // if so, put in list
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($typevalue as $label => $value) {
          $label = is_int($label)? '': "$label: "; // only print text
          echo "<li>$label$value</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
      }

      // if not...
      else {
        echo $typevalue;
      }

      echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>\n";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Using unordered lists to help display the information in a readable manner. To see with only break tags as in the question, see [PHP Sandbox - Original](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af0e2a32c2055f3d7133f385c44382727082939d)

[PHP Sandbox - Unordered Lists](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5b7823003e5a557e391efb35690b7666899b753)